# How to project a sum of a field in a sub-document based on a condition in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a Customer collection with the following document:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  firstname: "John",
  lastname: "Doe",
  credits: [
    {
      cDate: "2020-01-16",
      cAmount: 350
    },
    {
      cDate: "2021-02-07",
      cAmount: 180
    },
    {
      cDate: "2021-06-25",
      cAmount: 650
    },
  ]
}
{
  "_id": 2,
  firstname: "Bob",
  lastname: "Smith",
  credits: [
    {
      cDate: "2020-03-19",
      cAmount: 200
    },
    {
      cDate: "2020-08-20",
      cAmount: 90
    },
    {
      cDate: "2021-11-11",
      cAmount: 300
    },
  ]
}
```

Now I would like to return the total spent for a specific year i.e. 2021.
The data should look something like this:

```
{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe", "total": 830},
{"firstname": "Bob", "lastname": "Smith", "total": 300}
```

First I tried to match the records that contain `cDates` within the expected year (2021) to reduce the number of records (the actual dataset has hundreds of customers) and then projected the wanted fields:

```
Customer.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      credits: {
        $elemMatch: {
          cDate: {
            $gte: ISODate("2021-01-01"),
            $lte: ISODate("2021-12-31"),
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {      
      _id: 0,
      firstname: 1,
      lastname: 1,
      total: {
        $sum: "$credits.cAmount",
      },
    },
  }
])
```

the result is:

```
{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe", "total": 1180},
{"firstname": "Bob", "lastname": "Smith", "total": 590}
```

Almost there, now I'd like to skip the credit records that do not contain the expected year (2021), so that only the values with a `cDate` equal to 2021 are calculated.
The `$match` I kept the same and I tried to add a `$cond` in the `$project` bit.

```
Customer.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      credits: {
        $elemMatch: {
          cDate: {
            $gte: ISODate("2021-01-01"),
            $lte: ISODate("2021-12-31"),
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {      
      _id: 0,
      firstname: 1,
      lastname: 1,
      total: {        
        $cond: {
          if: { credits: { cDate: { regex: "2021-" } } }, // if cDate contains 2021-
          then: { $sum: "$credits.cAmount" },             // add the cAmount
          else: { $sum: 0 }                               // else add 0
        },
      },
    },
  }
])
```

This results is still the same, all totals get calulated from all years.

```
{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe", "total": 1180},
{"firstname": "Bob", "lastname": "Smith", "total": 590}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property `cDate` has string value, you can not match by date type,

- `$match` `cDate` by `$regex` and match `"2021"` year
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `credits` array, set initial value to 0
- `$substr` to get substring of the `cDate` from 0 index and 4 character that is year
- `$cond` to check is substring is `"2021"` then `$sum` the initial value with `cAmount` otherwise return initial value

```
Customer.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "credits.cDate": {
        $regex: "2021"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      firstname: 1,
      lastname: 1,
      total: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$credits",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  { $substr: ["$$this.cDate", 0, 4] },
                  "2021"
                ]
              },
              { $sum: ["$$value", "$$this.cAmount"] },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OdjJdxqbmAe)